# Are we able to remote access Ubuntu 16.04 with default setting?

Tags: remote-access

Freshly installed Ubuntu 16.04, Desktop, AMD64 on a company computer, but forgot to enable remote access before leaving the office.
With company VPN, I can ping the IP, I have root password.
Am I able to remote access the computer?

Comment: How do you want to access it? If you want to access it via ssh (or sftp), you must install an ssh server, for example `openssh-server`. See [this link for more details](https://askubuntu.com/questions/966229/why-am-i-unable-to-create-a-shared-folder/966245#966245). And you may need some help from a system admin at the company to get through the firewall of the company.

Comment: @user68186 Question updated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## No, the default desktop installation does not run any servers that open any port

So, if you forgot to enable Desktop Sharing or install `openssh-server`, you won't be able to access the computer remotely.

When you enable remote access for the first time, it will walk you through the installation of the the needed parts. The default program for remote access is for remote desktop sharing (and control). The user who is sharing the desktop must be logged in locally for the remote user to access the desktop remotely. So, once you enable remote desktop sharing, remember not to log out before you leave for home.

There are many ways to get around this limitation of desktop sharing. I found http://askubuntu.com/questions/229989/how-to-setup-x11vnc-to-access-with-graphical-login-screen most useful.

If you want just command line access to your your office computer, or use Nautlius to remotely access files and folders follow [Why am I unable to create a shared folder?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/966229/why-am-i-unable-to-create-a-shared-folder/966245#966245) as indicated by sudous in the comments.

Hope this helps